# GLTF 2.0 sample BoxTexture mapping problem

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, gltf

I parsed the sample boxTexture gltf file and extracted the below data,

```
00 : position: -0.5,-0.5,0.5, tex_coords: 6,0,
01 : position: 0.5,-0.5,0.5,  tex_coords: 5,0,
02 : position: -0.5,0.5,0.5,  tex_coords: 6,1,
03 : position: 0.5,0.5,0.5,   tex_coords: 5,1,
04 : position: 0.5,0.5,0.5,   tex_coords: 4,0,
05 : position: 0.5,-0.5,0.5,  tex_coords: 5,0,
06 : position: 0.5,0.5,-0.5,  tex_coords: 4,1,
07 : position: 0.5,-0.5,-0.5, tex_coords: 5,1,
08 : position: -0.5,0.5,0.5,  tex_coords: 2,0,
09 : position: 0.5,0.5,0.5,   tex_coords: 1,0,
10 : position: -0.5,0.5,-0.5, tex_coords: 2,1,
11 : position: 0.5,0.5,-0.5,  tex_coords: 1,1,
12 : position: 0.5,-0.5,0.5,  tex_coords: 3,0,
13 : position: -0.5,-0.5,0.5, tex_coords: 4,0,
14 : position: 0.5,-0.5,-0.5, tex_coords: 3,1,
15 : position: -0.5,-0.5,-0.5,tex_coords: 4,1,
16 : position: -0.5,-0.5,0.5, tex_coords: 3,0,
17 : position: -0.5,0.5,0.5,  tex_coords: 2,0,
18 : position: -0.5,-0.5,-0.5,tex_coords: 3,1,
19 : position: -0.5,0.5,-0.5, tex_coords: 2,1,
20 : position: -0.5,-0.5,-0.5,tex_coords: 0,0,
21 : position: -0.5,0.5,-0.5, tex_coords: 0,1,
22 : position: 0.5,-0.5,-0.5, tex_coords: 1,0,
23 : position: 0.5,0.5,-0.5,  tex_coords: 1,1,

indices:
0,1,2,
3,2,1,
4,5,6,
7,6,5,
8,9,10,
11,10,9,
12,13,14,
15,14,13,
16,17,18,
19,18,17,
20,21,22,
23,22,21,
```

to generate the opengl model shown below,

[image]

As you can see here the problem is that the textures aren't applied properly,
what is the problem here? is there something wrong with the coordinates?
i can't seem to pinpoint where exactly I went wrong.

Comment: The vertex data looks right. You can inspect each accessor individually using the [glTF VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cesium.gltf-vscode) to verify that. Perhaps your rendering code has a mistake — It looks a bit like you may be using the position attribute instead of UVs?

Comment: cool, let me check and see if i've made any mistake in my rendering code.

Comment: thanks alot man, it did turn out to be a problem with my rendering code. Didnt set my VertexAttribPointer properly.